# How to access repo from other organizations with in the Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

In Azure DevOps, I have multiple organizations with in the same Azure subscription. Build orchestration pipelines, related repos spread across the organizations,  how to avoid duplicate service connections?

Scenario1 -> How to checkout code from  organization A repo, for a pipeline created in organization B. Is there any option available to share repo service connection to other organization ?

Scenario 2 -> Service connection created to access SonarQube from Org A, how to use the same service connection in one of the pipeline running in Org B ?

Answer (score 1):

> Scenario1 -> How to checkout code from organization A repo, for a pipeline created in organization B. Is there any option available to share repo service connection to other organization ?

The answer is yes.

You could create a service connection:

`New service connection`-> `Other Git`-> `Git repository URL`:

Type the git repository URL for another repos with Password/Token (optional).

However, you could not share the repo service connection to other organization.

> Scenario 2 -> Service connection created to access SonarQube from Org
> A, how to use the same service connection in one of the pipeline
> running in Org B ?
> Just as the second question in your first question, we could not use the same service connection in one of the pipeline.

According to the document [Manage service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

[image]

The service connection is an organization asset, and it cannot share assets with other organization. We have to create a new service connection for the Org B.